# Is it possible to configure NginX reverse proxy for udp Pritunl traffic?

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, wireguard

Pritunl server configured on Ubuntu VM inside LAN with IP 192.168.1.20. Pritunl uses process: pritunl-web on 443 TCP port:

```
tcp    LISTEN  0        4096                     *:443                  *:*      users:(("pritunl-web",pid=528539,fd=3))
```

and openvpn 24900 UDP port:

```
udp    UNCONN  0        0                  0.0.0.0:24900          0.0.0.0:*      users:(("openvpn",pid=528710,fd=5))
```

and UDP port 24990 (on both IPv4/IPv6) for wireguard:

```
udp    UNCONN  0        0                  0.0.0.0:24990          0.0.0.0:*
udp    UNCONN  0        0                     [::]:24990             [::]:*
```

On this VM also installed NginX. Is it possible to configure NginX reverse proxy exactly for UDP traffic of openvpn/wireguard processes like this:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 24000 udp reuseport;
        proxy_pass 192.168.1.20:24900;
    }
    server {
        listen 24100 udp reuseport;
        proxy_pass 192.168.1.20:24990;
    }
    server {
        listen 24100 udp reuseport;
        proxy_pass IPv6:24990;
    }

}
```

?
Where 24000 and 24100 are inbound opened ports on router.

p.s. As I understand SSL configuration for udp traffic does not need to add, isn't it?